# Getting the stream object in Collectors toMap method using Method References in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

I am trying to iterate a list using `stream()` and putting in a map, where the key is the steam element itself, and the value is an AtomicBoolean, true.

```
List<String> streamDetails = Arrays.asList("One","Two");
toReplay = streamDetails.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.toString(), new AtomicBoolean(true)));
```

I get the below errors at compile time.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to K
The method toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> x) -> {}, 
     AtomicBoolean)
```

What could I be doing wrong, what shall I replace my `x -> x.toString()` with?

Comment: `streamDetails.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v->new AtomicBoolean(true)));`

Comment: I would consider that you knew the syntax and this is just a typo since you already used a lambda for a `FunctionalInterface` in the same call => `Collectors.toMap(x -> x.toString(), new AtomicBoolean(true)))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new AtomicBoolean(true)` is an expression that is not valid for the second parameter to `Collectors.toMap`.

`toMap` here would want a `Function<? super String, ? extends AtomicBoolean>` (intended to convert a stream element (or type String) to a map value of your intended type, AtomicBoolean), and a correct argument could be:

```
Collectors.toMap(x -> x.toString(), x -> new AtomicBoolean(true))
```

Which can also be written using `Function.identity`:

```
Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> new AtomicBoolean(true))
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped. I am new to java-8 and have only recently been exploring its features.